# How to update a specific node from a Firebase database with Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a relative simple Firebase database which looks like this:

[image]

How can i update the `Room1` node? If i use this code, in stead of updating that node, it adds another one, with the new name, `Room2`.

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rooms");
Query updateQuery = databaseReference.child(Room1).orderByKey().equalTo(Room1);
updateQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        dataSnapshot.getRef().getParent().child("Room2").setValue("");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rooms1").setValue("your value here");` will be enough. Why you add all that code? Did you also want to detect whenever data changed?

Comment: All i want to do, is to change the name of `Room1` to `Room2`. If i do as you said, `Room1` gets a value like this: `"Room1": "Room2"`. How can i update only `Room1`?

Comment: Oh, rename? did you have `Room` custom object? if you have then it would be more easy. The concept is get all the data from `Room1`, and assign them to `Room` custom object. Then you remove `Room1` node from database. Then add new node called `Room2` and assign `Room` custom object into that new node.

Comment: Can you please write me some lines of code? Thanks!

Comment: honestly, it's a bit difficult to make that `Room` custom object (and my solution need that). Let me ask you, did `Room1` have child node other than `-Kah0vRP...`? if it only contain that as single node, I recomend you change your database structure

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of other child nodes like `-Kah0vRP...`. All i want to do, is to change the name of `Room1` in `Room2`. Is there another possibility to achieve this? Even if i need to change the database structure.

Comment: You cannot change keys of an existing node or move branches in the Firebase Database. There isn't an API for this. You'll need to create a copy and then delete the original. This has been asked before, so I'll find a duplicate.

Comment: I did not find that post, but thanks, it solved my problem. Creating a copy and than deleting the original is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Rooms").child(Room1);
databaseReference.setValue()
```

with whatever new value you want in the setValue() parentheses

Comment: Your answer is the same as koceeng's. It has the same result. All i want to do, is to change the name of Room1 to Room2. If i do as you said, Room1 gets a value like this: "Room1": "Room2". How can i update only Room1?