# How to update android firebase specific node data based on that node values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Following is my android firebase example structure.

[image: firebase example structure]

I know only groupID and userID, I want to update specific total value by based on groupID and userID. i have no idea please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a specific node from a Firebase database with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731924/how-to-update-a-specific-node-from-a-firebase-database-with-android)

Comment: My question is different, i want to retrieve/filter data first which node child has that groupID and userID then for that child i want to update total.

Comment: To retrieve you can use Firebase query . Whats the issue .have you tried . Post the code here .

Comment: I know retrieve. I need to update firebase child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your confusion :

Let me explain you :
For updating single value :

//For this you just need your node Id

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("useramounts").child("your_node_id");

 HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
 result.put("total", total);
 databaseReference.updateChildren(result);
```

Comment: can i get Node id by using groupID and userID. If so how

Comment: Thanks i found it